# Removing certain XML file entries

Tags: xml, notepad++

At the moment I am working with huge file which contains hundred thousands of xml entries, after changing them I have to upload them in specific systems as new database, the file contents looks like this:

```
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Product</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Home &gt; Connectors &gt; Power Entry</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">10430</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">CAMDEN-BOSS CONTACT, 6AWG, 75A CBCAG14</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">CONTACT, 6AWG, 75A; Connector Mounting:Cable; Contact Termination:Crimp; Current Rating:75A; SVHC:No SVHC (18-Jun-2012); Series:CBC; Voltage Rating:600V; Flammability Rating:UL94 V0; Wire Area Size Max:11mm; Wire Size AWG Max:6AWG; Wire Size AWG Min:6AWG&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Price for pack of: 1&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Country Of Origin: CN&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://LALA.co.uk/datasheets/1508502.pdf&quot;&gt;&lt;img alt=&quot;&quot; src=&quot;/ekmps/shops/LALA/resources/Design/icon-pdf.gif&quot; style=&quot;width: 16px; height: 16px;&quot; /&gt;&amp;nbsp;Technical Data Sheet&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br /&gt;</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
```

My job is to remove all the entries in which  there aren any links to .pdf files, examble above has it so would be left, but if there wouldnt be  "http://LALA.co.uk/datasheets/1508502.pdf" in description it should have been removed (all row), I can work with diferend things, from C# to.. So doesnt really matter of solution type, can anyone suggest me something?

Comment: You may not be able to do this in notepad++ or with regexes . It may be easier to read the file line by line in C# and skip those lines that contain <Cell> but don't contain pdf . You can do this with plain string find and without regexes

Comment: The worst thing is that I need to delete all row, not only the cell line... I think it could be done like that in notepad++, firstly to change text that row would be one line text no breaks and then to replace lines containing text .pdf with nothing, what do you think about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++ find (Ctrl+F)

```
<Row[^>]*>((?!\.pdf).)*?</Row>
```

Replace with

```
(leave blank)
```

"Regular expression" and ". matches newline" boxes have to be checked