# Using Notepad++, how do i select an entire XML node?

Tags: xml, function, replace, xml-parsing, notepad++

I have a huuuuuuuge XML File (1500 records) and i need to remove certain entries in it depending on their content. Since there's no specific rules of which one to keep and which one to remove, i have to do them one by one.

I would like to do it with the replace function (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>), and i would click "next" for those i want to keep, and "replace" for those i want to remove (leaving the "replace with" field empty.) I will be able to read and determine once it's highlighted (selected).

Here is that a node looks like :

```
 <Record>
     <itemname>Lego Fire Rescue</itemname>
     <itemnumber>6654721</itemnumber>
     <availableinv>19</availableinv>
     <ageplus>3</ageplus>
     <storeId>19</storeId> 
 </Record>
```

If it could select from `<Record>` to `</Record>` for each nodes that would be perfect.

Closest example i could find, would remove entries without .pdf : [Removing certain XML file entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987291/removing-certain-xml-file-entries)

Many, many thanks for you help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the replace dialog

```
Find what: (<Record>.*?</Record>)
Replace with: <blank>
```

At the bottom of the dialog, make sure **Regular expression** is selected and **. matches newline** is checked.

Comment: this doesn't really work if the ending tag is shared by multiple nodes within the one which needs to be removed